# _all.json not found

Tags: dxa, web8

I have installed DXA 1.4 on my SDL Web 8 System. When I try to visit a web page in the application, I get the following message:

> Item '/system/config/_all.json' not found for Localization '20'

Have I missed a step, or is this an indication of some problem in my environment.

Comment: Check the basics? Is it published? Does it show in the database? Anything else in logs?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Nuno, it was a question of checking the basics. I had not published it. And although it is obvious with 20-20 hindsight, it's probably helpful to have this reminder here. His other suggestion is also a good one: check the logs!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it really pays off to read the manual, which states you should publish the example site before you can request anything (since for starters the DXA web application configuration needs to be published from the CMS, the HTML design needs to be published from the CMS, and the homepage and its includes also need to be published, else there is no page to request), and if for whatever reason you don't want to publish the entire example publication, it even specifies exactly which pages you have to publish before you can request the homepage;

To publish the minimal set of items, select and publish the following Pages:

```
Home/_System/Publish Settings
Home/_System/Publish HTML Design
Home/_System/include/Content Tools
Home/_System/include/Footer
Home/_System/include/Header
Home/_System/include/Left Navigation
Home/_Error Page Not Found
Home/000 Home
Home/Sitemap
Home/_Navigation
```

As can be found here in the online docs: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-626FDF93-2D0B-4B3B-9CB1-9A0D7402FD82

So I think the reminder here should be read the manual, we didn't spend 20% of our developer budget on documentation just because it was fun...

Comment: I am facing the same issue on DXA 1.4 .NET. I have published all pages as mentioned in SDL documentation and checked my application folder `system/config _all.json` is there and all pages in Broker, but still facing the issue while rendering home page.
`error: '/system/config/_all.json' not found for Localization '6'`