# ERROR : _all.json' not found for Localization | DXA 1.4 .NET web 8.1.1

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.4, dxa-net

I have installed DXA 1.4 .NET on my SDL Web 8 System. When I hit application, I get the following message:

> Item '/system/config/_all.json' not found for Localization '6'

Site.log error

```
ERROR - Item '/system/config/_all.json' not found for Localization '6'
Sdl.Web.Common.DxaItemNotFoundException: Item '/system/config/_all.json' not found for Localization '6'
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Statics.BinaryFileManager.GetCachedFile(String urlPath, Localization localization) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Statics\BinaryFileManager.cs:line 89
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultProvider.GetStaticContentItem(String urlPath, Localization localization) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Mapping\DefaultProvider.cs:line 151
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.LoadStaticContentItem[T](String relativeUrl, T& deserializedObject) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\Localization.cs:line 367
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.Load() in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\Localization.cs:line 427
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.EnsureInitialized() in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\Localization.cs:line 149
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:line 96
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 23
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 51
2016-06-24 11:37:30,348 [10] WARN  - Item '/system/config/_all.json' not found for Localization '6'. Sending HTTP 404 (Not Found) response.
2016-06-24 11:37:30,348 [10] DEBUG - StaticContentModule.BeginRequest() exit. Duration: 223 ms.
```

i have published all pages as mentioned in sdl document and check my application folder system/config _all.json is there and all pages in borker but still facing the issue while rendering home page

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-626FDF93-2D0B-4B3B-9CB1-9A0D7402FD82

i have already referred below url but did not find any solution

> [_all.json not found](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14531/all-json-not-found)
>
> [Error on accessing website DXA 1.4](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14563/error-on-accessing-website-dxa-1-4)

```
> PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-TtmWebsite
> 
> 
> BaseUrls             : {http://localhost:90} CdEnvironmentId      :
> SampleCD EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging CdEnvironment        : 
> ScopedRepositoryKeys : {DxaSiteType, DxaExampleSite} Id               
> : Website2 ExtensionProperties  : {}
> 
> BaseUrls             : {http://localhost:86} CdEnvironmentId      :
> SampleCD EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging CdEnvironment        : 
> ScopedRepositoryKeys : {} Id                   : visitorsweb
> ExtensionProperties  : {}
```

Kindly let me know if i missed something

Comment: Where did you check the presence of `_all.json` exactly? It should be in folder `BinaryData\6\system\config` within you DXA Web App root. But the exception implies is not.  It should be retrieved from the CD Content Store (broker) in that case, though...

Comment: Check the `BINARY_VARIANTS` table in your CD Content Store to verify that `_all.json'` is indeed published in Publication 6.

Comment: @RickPannekoek its in multiple folders of site website\system\ _all.json , resources\ _all.json, config\ _all.json, mappings\ _all.json and in broker BINARY_VARIANTS table publication 6 VARIANT_ID ="statics-bootstrap" PATH and URL = /system/_all.json all other folder mapping is available in broker

Comment: Weird. We have observed similar spurious errors on SDL Web 8 systems with UGC cartridge enabled.  Do you have that on your system? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: Oh, BTW: note that the URL of the BINARY_VARIANT has to be `/system/config/_all.json`

Comment: @RickPannekoek No i did not install UGC cartridge and yes BINARY_VARIANT has url  /system/config/_all.json

Comment: Ok, then  the only further advice I can give is to debug your Web App to see how it fails exactly.

Comment: I get the same problem with the sample site on publication 5,  in the default installation, so what would I debug?

Comment: are you using same website url which you registered with this publication id?

Comment: Changing media path to other folder can cause this issue as the BinaryData folder meant to be acting as cache and your all.json has the info about it, if that's getting read from diff file you probably need to find a way to tell your DXA application to check for settings (all.json) from your specified place. Also check if you see all.json at the place you are storing your media?

Answer (score -2):

Hi the issue is by default DXA searches binary files inside `BinaryData/5/`, so you have to set this path in Deployer `storage.config` to publish binaries inside `BinaryData/5`. Here 5 is your publication ID. For instant solution create the `binarydata/5` folder at your root application and paste system folder inside that folder so you path will be eg. `Webapp/BinaryData/5/system`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you have to configure your deployer to store everything (pages, DCPs and binaries) in the CD Content Store. See the DXA Docs: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-6D3337B6-FC47-479A-A38B-6AF3C53B9A51

Comment: You got me confused by saying that the files were present in the `BinaryData` directory (which is DXA's filesystem cache of binaries stored in the CD Content Store)...

Comment: i have configured deployer to publish (pages,DCP) in CD Content Store , binarys to file system and i have not mentioned that the binaries are present inside BinaryData  in my case its present inside `website\system\_all.json` as mentioned above. here website is my application root folder .